# I need to implement authentication on my web app

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, firebase-authentication

My scenario:

A Google Apps Script Web Application served from its server-side index.html to fill the students score on a spreadsheet.
The script is embedded as iframe in a website page hosted on Firebase.

I need a way to protect this web app and make it only accessible for specific users via Firebase Auth. username and password.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to protect static web content with Firebase Auth.  What you can do instead is is protect access to your backend using a ID token provided by the client to the server, and the server can validate that the user can take action.  You would use the Firebase Admin SDK on the backend to [validate the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Comment: thank you dear, but i am not running a server app on my pc, i just upload my web stuff to Firebase Hosting using Node.js.

Comment: That doesn't change the answer at all.  Firebase Auth can't be used to protect static content deployed to Firebase Hosting.  Once you deploy, all of the content will be available to anyone with an internet connection.  Whatever you are using on the backend to update the spreadsheet will need to use a user ID token provided by Firebase Auth.

Comment: i mean to follow your steps i need to install Admin SDK, so do i have to run server app on my pc? although my pc ip is not exposed to public internet. thank you again for your time. [Beginner]

Comment: It's up to you to figure out how to make it work for your setup.  Stack Overflow can't provided personalized, guided walkthroughs for stuff like this.  If you have a new specific question about how to use the Admin SDK, please post another question.